# Jenkins fails to execute app:processDebugResources with AarResourcesCompilerTransform error

Tags: android, jenkins, android-appcompat, android-testing

I am trying to run all ui test for my app using jenkins ci/cd, but i constantly run into error, which cause by fail of app:processDebugResources command. When i build project at Android Studio it doesn't throw any error and build correctly.

After executing in jenkins `connectedAndroidTest` gradle command :

```
Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED   

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
  * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform appcompat-1.3.0.aar (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\9398b1795b0a45e239a8370198c80687\transformed\appcompat-1.3.0.
         > Android resource compilation failed
           ERROR:AAPT: C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\5b50c60af17e66ade7be3083cf0fe04d\transformed\androidx.appcompat: error: РќРµ СѓРґР°РµС‚СЃСЏ РЅР°Р№С‚Рё СѓРєР°Р·Р°РЅРЅС‹Р№ С„Р°Р№Р». (2).
           
               
   > Failed to transform appcompat-1.3.0.aar (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\9398b1795b0a45e239a8370198c80687\transformed\appcompat-1.3.0.
         > Android resource compilation failed
           ERROR:AAPT: C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\5b50c60af17e66ade7be3083cf0fe04d\transformed\androidx.appcompat: error: РќРµ СѓРґР°РµС‚СЃСЏ РЅР°Р№С‚Рё СѓРєР°Р·Р°РЅРЅС‹Р№ С„Р°Р№Р». (2).
           
               
   > Failed to transform core-1.6.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.6.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\619c06b67a6c841ffa9224727d661a21\transformed\core-1.6.0.
         > Android resource compilation failed
           ERROR:AAPT: C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\308760ecdbed89bb153e932d840e53f3\transformed\androidx.core: error: РќРµ СѓРґР°РµС‚СЃСЏ РЅР°Р№С‚Рё СѓРєР°Р·Р°РЅРЅС‹Р№ С„Р°Р№Р». (2).
```

Error Failed to transform core-1.6.0.aar repeat several times in report, but error text are the same every time.

My build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
    id 'com.shazam.fork'
}

apply plugin: 'com.shazam.fork'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    defaultConfig {
        configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0' }
        }
        applicationId "app.converter" // it's ok, nevermind
        minSdkVersion 30
        //noinspection OldTargetApi
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 5
        versionName "5"
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    compileOptions{
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        buildFeatures {
            viewBinding true
        }


    }

}

dependencies {
    ....
    //noinspection GradleDependency
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
   ....

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"


    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
}
```

Thanks in advance, will provide additional info on request.

UPD :
Adding  `-g C:\gradle-cache` to gradle tasks in Jenkins triggered a new error:

```
   22:14:03 * What went wrong:
    22:14:03 Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugAndroidTestResources'.
    22:14:03 > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
    22:14:03    > Android resource linking failed
    22:14:03      C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\ConverterKT\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debugAndroidTest\AndroidManifest.xml: error: failed to load XML file: РќРµ СѓРґР°РµС‚СЃСЏ РЅР°Р№С‚Рё СѓРєР°Р·Р°РЅРЅС‹Р№ С„Р°Р№Р». (2).
```

UPD 2.
Updated gradle to 7.5 and addtional exception show up, however termial run in Android Studio

```
21:01:23 FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.
21:01:23 
21:01:23 1: Task failed with an exception.
21:01:23 -----------
21:01:23 * What went wrong:
21:01:23 Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
21:01:23 > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
21:01:23    > Android resource linking failed
21:01:23      C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\ConverterKT\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug\AndroidManifest.xml: error: failed to load XML file: РќРµ СѓРґР°РµС‚СЃСЏ РЅР°Р№С‚Рё СѓРєР°Р·Р°РЅРЅС‹Р№ С„Р°Р№Р». (2).
21:01:23 
21:01:23 
21:01:23 * Try:
21:01:23 > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
21:01:23 > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
21:01:23 > Run with --scan to get full insights.
21:01:23 ==============================================================================
21:01:23 
21:01:23 2: Task failed with an exception.
21:01:23 -----------
21:01:23 * What went wrong:
21:01:23 Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugAndroidTestResources'.
21:01:23 > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
21:01:23    > Android resource linking failed
21:01:23      C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Jenkins\.jenkins\workspace\ConverterKT\app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debugAndroidTest\AndroidManifest.xml: error: failed to load XML file: РќРµ СѓРґР°РµС‚СЃСЏ РЅР°Р№С‚Рё СѓРєР°Р·Р°РЅРЅС‹Р№ С„Р°Р№Р». (2).
```

Comment: To build in jenkins are you using some specific plugin or a bash/batch script? If you run this code in the Android Studio terminal is it able to build?

Comment: @madlymad           
I use out of box jenkins in my browser.
Yes, using terminal, i am able to run and finish tests without any exception.

Comment: This text is really strange `РќРµ СѓРґР°РµС‚СЃСЏ РЅР°Р№С‚Рё СѓРєР°Р·Р ` do you have any such characters to your manifest? Is it UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: @madlymad Yes, <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Comment: I mean the file encoding at the right bottom of the screen shown in the android studio status bar. Which indicates the actual encoding of the file. Sometimes this is inherited from the system and it can cause strange things!

Comment: @madlymad still UTF-8. Maybe it's connected to Windows OS localization ? I am using Ukrainian one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(One of) the `AndroidManifest.xml` seems to be corrupt. One can write `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` into just any XML file, while the file itself doesn't feature UTF-8 encoding, this does not matter the least. Or plugin `id 'kotlin-parcelize'` might be related; usually this one is not required. I'd also suggest to get rid of this, unless there is a good reason:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy { force 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0' }
}
```

While it won't even build locally, forget about building on Jenkins.